# Do SAS to SATA cables work interchangeably?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, sas

I need to boot a sever OS that lives on a SAS type Hard Drive, from a desktop machine (a server got a little bit wet and the PSU's have blown).

It's a Dell PowerEdge T620 that's gone down and I just need to grab the data from the drives if possible.

If I buy a SAS to SATA cable will it boot?

Comment: Specifically, you mean a cable that connects a SAS disk to a SATA controller, right? I think that depends on the controller/motherboard you'll be using, not on the server that's already fried...

Answer (score 1):

SAS and SATA use different signaling voltages. Using SATA on a SAS backplane will function but the opposite will not, as a consequence of the voltage ranges.

Your scenario seems to be ok, before your buy a SAS to SATA cable, you’d better consult Dell support, they may give you some suggestion about cable type.